# How can I recognize particular ASP Web application from other IE windows?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, internet-explorer, process

We have a .Net based application which users close by mistake very frequently. I want to disable close button for which I have found few sample applications. I searched internet for disabling close button but almost all applications work on user32.dll using `this.handle` method as mentioned under:

```
public void DisableCloseButton() //A standard void function to invoke EnableMenuItem()
        {
            EnableMenuItem(GetSystemMenu(this.Handle, false), SC_CLOSE, MF_GRAYED);
        }
```

I want to disable close button of one particular ASP Web Application. Simple solution is to disable it for all IE windows, however, this will effect other web browsing. Therefore, I need to check possibility of any mechanism based on which I can differentiate between target IE application and others.

Apologies for any ambiguity in the question.

Comment: Holy wat...destroy all software....

Answer (score 0):

This is 100% an absolutely bad idea. It violates all ui standards and is dangerous to try to intercept close messages for applications you did not write.

If you want to make sure they don't lose work add a save prompt within the application on document unload and allow them to save.